# Filesharing solution for small architecture firm

Tags: file-management, file-synchronization, web-server

I run a small architecture firm. Until recently this firm was just composed of myself and I used Google Drive to share files between my laptop and office computers. However I've recently began to work with more collaborators and am hiring someone and Google Drive is no longer cutting the mustard.

The main problems:

- I work on fairly large CAD/model/drawings files (~5MB - ~100MB) that sometimes require non-trivial amounts of time to sync. It has happened a number of times that I work on a file at home, it syncs to the server, then I get to the office and open the same file, but I open it before it has been updated by the server. The process of opening the file then creates a new sync entry that updates on the server, so I need to go into the google drive file history and manually correct it. A few times I haven't noticed what's happened and have began editing and saving the new file on my office computer, and when I eventually notice what's happened have had to go back and manually reconcile the files which is extremely time consuming
- When I'm working on a project with someone else I need to keep in constant communication about who has what file open, because Drive doesn't prevent someone in from opening a file that a different person has open in another location. Again, this has occasionally resulted in two branches of the same file being made that subsequently need to be manually reconciled

I basically just need something that reliably locks files for editing when open and also (if possible) locks files for editing until they've checked with the server that the local file is up to date.

At my old firm we had an actual server that I accessed via VPN that worked well in both of these regards. While I'm moderately tech savvy setting something like this up is outside of my capabilities. I could hire an IT consultant, but I'm wondering if there is a maybe a service I'm not aware of that would accomplish what I'm after. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: "At my old firm we had an actual server that I accessed via VPN that worked well in both of these regards" You mean it had a locking feature and prevented others from editing locked files, right? Or did it somehow sync faster than Google Drive?

Comment: Yes, it locked files for editing. As far as sync speeds go, it didn't sync per se. As opposed to saving a local file, which would then prompt a sync software to update the remote file to match the local file, you would directly edit the actual remote file. The actual act of saving took longer but all files on the server were always up-to-date.